# Quantum uncertainty can explain the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

In the recent paper "Riemann Hypothesis as an Uncertainty Relation" (http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2435) the author claims that the presence of zeros out of the critical line may lead to the violation of a Heisenberg-type uncertainty relation. Is that work a proof of Riemann's hypothesis?

Comment: While the uncertainty relation comes from the Robertson-Schroedinger inequality, the main ingredient is the canonical commutation relation of X and P. I haven't read the article so I don't know what the Heisemberg - type uncertainty relation is. But from my previous thought, that wouldn't be a proof as the basis of the uncertainty relation is a physical postulate.

Comment: @Barefeg I've only skimmed it, but I think the paper is going in the other direction: identify a quantum physical system where the Riemann zeta function is used, note that QM implies there is an uncertainty relation, then by the way the model is constructed, that uncertainty relation implies the Riemann hypothesis.  Seems to be using physics to "prove" mathematics! (maybe that's what you were saying anyway...)

Comment: More on Riemann hypothesis: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=riemann+hypothesis